# Displaying PDF files white on black

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-reader

I couldn't find the option to enable it on Adobe Reader or Foxit Reader. I don't think Sumatra has it neither. Can someone help me? White pages are starting to hurt my eyes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Foxit

```
Tools -> Preferences -> Documents -> Document Colors Options
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If someone's still looking for the option in sumatra, go to Settings -> Advanced options and change the following lines

```
FixedPageUI [
TextColor = #000000(make this #ffffff)
BackgroundColor = #ffffff(make this #000000)
SelectionColor = #f5fc0c
WindowMargin = 2 4 2 4
PageSpacing = 4 4
]
```