# Forcing grayscale PDF to Black and White?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader, foxit-reader

I have a large color PDF that I can easily view greyscale in Foxit Reader:

[image: foxit color controls]

Unfortunately various bits of text end up in ridiculously light shades of grey.
Similar, but not direct, questions include:

- [Displaying PDF files white on black](https://superuser.com/questions/169521/displaying-pdf-files-white-on-black)
- [Converting a PDF to black & white with ghostscript](https://superuser.com/questions/200378/converting-a-pdf-to-black-white-with-ghostscript)
- [Convert a colored PDF into a white/black](https://superuser.com/questions/488813/convert-a-colored-pdf-into-a-white-black)

How can I force a PDF to display only in pure black and white?

Comment: Where does the file come from? Perhaps it is better to make it black and white in the original format?

Comment: It is an autocad drawing, but I don't have autocad.

Comment: Personally, i do hate it. So many years - 2017, FoxItReader 8.1, the problem still not solved. Yet. And plenty-plenty non-printable ok docs... And command line converting instead of using already present checkboxes... I do hate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) is free and cross-platform.  This command should work:

```
convert <input> -threshold xx% <output>
```

For example:

```
convert original.pdf -threshold 50% new.pdf
```

You'll have to set the threshold to taste.

Comment: Hi @Kev , would you tell me how to do that in `IMDisplay.exe` , please?

Comment: @SantosaSandy sorry I honestly never use `IMDisplay.exe` so I don't know whether it's possible nor, if so, how.

Comment: Can you check command for current version?

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [answer by Kev](https://superuser.com/a/1657670/514126) with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). ImageMagick will convert a vector pdf to raster at 72 dpi. An alpha channel might also cause the conversion to fail.

Try: `magick -density 288 original.pdf -alpha off -colorspace gray -auto-threshold otsu new.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid downloading and working with the command line in ImageMagick, there's an online tool that can create pure Black and White from PDFs:

https://supertool.org/convert-color-pdfs-to-black-and-white/

The B&W Threshold and reverse features may help with light elements.