# Printing a Pdf in black and white without gray scale

Tags: pdf, printing

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to print a pdf in black and white without gray scale.
I tried to install ImageMagic.exe, but it does not open Pdf.

[Forcing grayscale PDF to Black and White?](https://superuser.com/questions/543293/forcing-grayscale-pdf-to-black-and-white)

---

EDIT:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If ImageMagic gave you an error, please [edit] your question to include that.

Comment: Hello @Worthwelle, the software does not support the pdf format.

Comment: Going by your error, it looks like it's not finding Ghostscript correctly. Can you verify that Ghostscript is installed and added to your `PATH` variable correctly?

Comment: @Worthwelle, ok now I installed Ghostscript. When I open pdf there is not the image, but a chessboard. I tried also to save the image in Pdf as a TIFF, in this way it works, but I don't know how convert it in black.